# Android Studio can not 'react-native start', How to fix it?

Tags: android, xcode, android-studio, react-native

There are 4 way to run React Native APL.

- react-native run-android
- react-native run-iso
- XCODE
- Android Studio

  `react-native start` works with another terminal screen,on `react-native run-android`, `react-native run-iso`, `XCODE`.
  But  Android Studio does not work, and error is as follows.

> [ 12-14 14:02:59.506  2905: 2928 E/         ]
>    Unable to load script from assets: index.android.bundle
>   E/unknown:React: Exception in native call from JS
>                    com.facebook.react.devsupport.JSException: Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly
>                        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
>                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
>                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:196)
>                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
>                     Caused by: com.facebook.jni.CppException: Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly
>                        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
>                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
>                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31) 
>                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:196) 
>                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
>   W/unknown:React: Packager connection already open, nooping.
>   W/unknown:React: Calling JS function after bridge has been destroyed.

Is there any fix on this error?

Thanks
Shoji

Answer (score 0):

I found the workaround for Android Studio.

on the terminal windows, do "react-native start"

then reload the app in Android Studio.

This work for me to debug React Native APL on Android Studio.

But My original question was,
In Android Studio, run command can not start package manager automatically  like XCODE dose.

Is there anyone to get work run with "start package manager automatically"? like XCODE dose.

Thanks

Shoji